# Linmodem MD563X-HaM

Tags: 16.04, modem

Is it possible to install HaM driver on kernel 4?

I couldn't find any useful info about it.

Are there any other alternatives?

Ambient Technologies Inc HaM controllerless modem (rev 02

Dan